# adding a manager back into swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a swarm cluster with two nodes. 1 Manager and 1 worker. I am running my application on worker node and to run a test case, I force remove manager from docker swarm cluster.

My application continues to work, but I would like to know if there is any possibility to add back the force removed manager in the cluster again. (I don't remember the join-token and neither have them copied anywhere)

I understand docker advises to have odd number of manager nodes to maintain quorum, but would like to know if docker has addressed such scenarios anywhere.

Comment: I believe in your case you have to use "--force-new-cluster" flag and move the nodes over to the new manager node.

Comment: does not work. When you force create a new cluster, you get new join-token. My worker nodes are still supporting the existing application services and for me to add them to new swarm cluster, I need to remove them from existing swarm and then add them to the new cluster. If I do this, my application would stop.

Answer (score 0):

docker swarm init --force-new-cluster --advertise-addr node01:2377

When you run the docker swarm init command with the --force-new-cluster flag, the Docker Engine where you run the command becomes the manager node of a single-node swarm which is capable of managing and running services. The manager has all the previous information about services and tasks, worker nodes are still part of the swarm, and services are still running. You need to add or re-add manager nodes to achieve your previous task distribution and ensure that you have enough managers to maintain high availability and prevent losing the quorum.

Comment: force-new-cluster would work when you have an active manager in an inconsistent cluster that would reuse the raft copy and build a new cluster using it, keeping the cluster configuration intact. However this solution does not seem feasible when I have 1 manager cluster and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

How about create new cluster from your previously manager machine and let the worker leave previous cluster to join the new one? That seems like the only possible solution for me, since your cluster now does not have any managers and the previous manager now not in any cluster, you can just create a new cluster and let other workers join the new one.

```
# In previously manager machine
$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr <manager ip address>
# *copy the generated command for worker to join new cluster after this command

# In worker machine
$ docker swarm leave
# *paste and execute the copied command here
```